# How to detect focusout on parent div not on child div in Angular4

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a custom autocomplete element. It consists of a input field, a button, and a div that contains the autocompletes. I want the behaviour that when i click outside the inputbox or the dropdown it invokes a callback that saves whatever is in the input field and if i click on a dropdown selection i want it to invoke the event that selects what i clicked and saves that.

But currently instead of working as exptected, when i click on the dropdown the focusout gets called, dropdown does not close, and on the second click it actually selects the dropdown value.

This is the component:

```
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm " (focusout)="blur($event)">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="userInput" title="{{userInput}}" (ngModelChange)="onValueChanged($event)"
    (focus)="$event.target.select()">
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" (click)="showPredefinedOptions()">
    </button>
    <div *ngIf="showDropdown" [ngClass]="{'dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right':true, 'show-address-autocomplete':showDropdown}">
      <div *ngIf="currentUserAddresses">
        <a *ngFor="let item of currentUserAddresses" class="dropdown-item ekat-dropdown-item" (click)="chooseAddress(item)">{{item}}</a>
        <div class="divider dropdown-divider"></div>
      </div>
      <a *ngFor="let item of currentResult" class="dropdown-item ekat-dropdown-item" (click)="chooseAddress(item)">{{item}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Insside the ts file i have a line  @Output() focusOut: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter(); that defines the focusoutevent to which i subscribe to.

And this is how im using it:

```
<td> <address-autocomplete [value]="product.defaultDeliveryAddress ? defaultAddress : product.deliveryAddress"  (onSelect)="onAddressChanged($event, product)"
                                 [userAddresses]="userAddressed" (onWritten)="onAddressWritten($event, product)" (focusOut)="focusOut(product)">></address-autocomplete></td>
```

Why is the focusout invoked when i click on the dropdown element?

Comment: Focus basically works on Input fields so once you click outside input field it will trigger focusout on parent div no matter you have clicked inside that parent div or outside it.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to use [Angular's Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) for this:

```html
<input type="text" [formControl]="inputControl">

<select [formControl]="selectControl">
  <!-- ... -->
</select>
```

```js
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class MyComponent {
  inputControl = new FormControl(null, { updateOn: 'blur' });
  selectControl = new FormControl(null, { updateOn: 'change' });

  ngOnInit() {
    inputControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      // ...
    });
    selectControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      // ...
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, if the change event on select is fired the onblur event must not fire.